# input shape error at keras model for next frame prediction

Tags: python, keras, conv-neural-network, lstm

I have a frame series of videos. I want to build a keras model that will predict the next frame. 97 images make up my input dataset. I plan the output of each image to be the next image.

For this, I built the following model. Suppose the width and height values are 224 x 224.

```
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import ConvLSTM2D, BatchNormalization, Conv2DTranspose
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow import keras
from tensorflow.keras import layers

# Define the number of ConvLSTM layers
num_layers = 3

# Define the model
model = Sequential()

# Add the first ConvLSTM layer
model.add(ConvLSTM2D(filters=64, kernel_size=(3, 3), padding='same', input_shape=(None, 224, 224, 3), return_sequences=True))
model.add(BatchNormalization())

# Add the remaining ConvLSTM layers
for i in range(num_layers - 1):
    model.add(ConvLSTM2D(filters=64, kernel_size=(3, 3), padding='same', return_sequences=True))
    model.add(BatchNormalization())

# Add the final layer to generate the predicted image
model.add(Conv2DTranspose(filters=3, kernel_size=(3, 3), padding='same', activation='sigmoid'))

model.summary()

# Compile the model
model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='mse')
```

I get the following error. I couldn't figure out what caused the error:

```
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
\<ipython-input-15-3d4ff6ccc6f8\> in \<cell line: 24\>()
22
23 # Add the final layer to generate the predicted image
\---\> 24 model.add(Conv2DTranspose(filters=3, kernel_size=(3, 3), padding='same', activation='sigmoid'))
25
26

2 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages/keras/layers/convolutional/conv2d_transpose.py in build(self, input_shape)
203         input_shape = tf.TensorShape(input_shape)
204         if len(input_shape) != 4:
\--\> 205             raise ValueError(
206                 "Inputs should have rank 4. "
207                 f"Received input_shape={input_shape}."

ValueError: Inputs should have rank 4. Received input_shape=(None, None, 224, 224, 64).
```

I think I am not setting the model input data properly. I tried but I couldn't make the input shape properly.

Comment: You defined input shape: `input_shape=(None, 224, 224, 3)` and passed `input_shape=(None, None, 224, 224, 64)`. Even reshaping won't help here, because after ignoring "extra" dimensions (the None ones) the data doesn't match 224*224*3 != 224*224*64. First one seems to be a 3 channel image (e.g. RGB channels or HSV and shape 224 x 224), not sure what is the 2nd one. Looks like you are "weirdly" reading images you pass to your network.